# How to check if a string contains a series of exactly 10 consecutive digits?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I check if a string contains at least **1** series of *exactly* **10** *consecutive* **digits** ?

For example:

`1234567890` **PASS**

`asdf 1234567890 asdf` **PASS**

`asdf 1234567890 asdf 1234567890` **PASS**

`asdf1234567890asdf` **PASS**

`asdf 123456789 asdf` **FAIL**

`asdf 12345678901 asdf` **FAIL**

`asdf 12345 67890 asdf` **FAIL**

etc...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @JohnConde: I tried `if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $string)` but it did not work.  I'm not very familiar with regex.

Comment: Is 5678901234 expected to pass?

Comment: Ranking 0 above 9 leads me to believe that the series is allows to wrap

Comment: I don't think he actually requires that the digits be in numeric sequence, that's just how he wrote his examples.

Comment: Got it. I was making it harder then it was.

Comment: @Barmar Question states: exactly 10 **consecutive** digits

Comment: I think he means "adjacent" when he wrote "consecutive".

Comment: Lol. Write you want tomato, you will get potato ^^ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(^|\D)\d{10}($|\D)/
```

This matches 10 digits, preceded by either the beginning of the line or a non-digit, followed by the end of the line or a non-digit.

[REGEXR](http://regexr.com?34ss1)

Comment: This works, thanks!  Could you please explain what it's doing exactly that makes yours work and the other 2 solutions not?

Comment: The others don't check for a non-digit before and after, they just check for the 10 consecutive digits. Duffmaster33's answer looks like it checks for a non-digit, but it doesn't because `*` matches zero repetitions.

Comment: Thanks!  I get what `\d{10}` does, but what do `(^|\D)` and `($|\D)` do exactly?

Comment: The only problem is it would also match 1234512345 also :) It does not take order into consideration

Comment: But wouldn't 1111111111 pass this test as well. Breaks to consecutive requirement

Comment: It would, you can try my solution.

Comment: @Orangepill I think he just meant "adjacent", not "numerically increasing".

Comment: @Programmer - `(^|\D)` means "either the beginning of the line or a nondigit"; `($|\D)` means "either the end of the line or a nondigit".  It means that 10 digits won't match if they're in the middle of a longer series of digits - it has to be exactly 10 digits in a row, not 11 or 12.

Comment: @Programmer You need to read a regexp tutorial, that's really basic stuff.

Comment: If you go to the regexr link and hover your mouse over the regexp, it will explain each piece of it in a pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead and lookbehind for anything that is not a digit.  note that this is not the same as a non-digit match.  Also the only capturing group (if you use the parens) contains precisely the 10 digit number you're looking for.

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/g7y06)

```
(?<![0-9])([0-9]{10})(?![0-9])
```

-- or --  (same thing shorter)

```
(?<!\d)(\d{10})(?!\d)
```

Comment: `\d` is not always the exactly the same thing as `[0-9]`. It also depend on the flag.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

preg_match("/\d{10}/u", $input)

or maybe

preg_match("\d{10}", $input)

I'm going off hand here, I don't have an editor open to check these.

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  It incorrectly passes `asdf 12345678901 asdf`.

Comment: Your second try isn't even valid regexp syntax, it's missing the delimiters.